# Как добавить другой сайта на локалке помимо localhost?

Tags: сервер, openserver

Сам пользуюсь Open Server, в domains - папка localhost. Если я не хочу в ней ничего делать, то как мне добавить определить другую папку на сервере?

Answer (score 0):

Создаете в папке domains папку с Вашим проектом и все, и в включенном сервере во вкладке мои сайты подтянет сайт с той папки.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик!

Comment: всегда пожалуйста и всегда за лайк если помогло) Хорошего дня)